# jQuery Focus() or keypress() not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, keypress

I have the code blow for tabbing through 2 fields and it has no effect in IE and Chrome, it seems it runs nothing (for example I get nothing when I put alert) and in Firefox it runs with some bug (it jumps twice there) where do you think the problem is, I'm developing in by ASP.Net and jQuery version 1.3.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TextBox1").keypress(function (e) {
        var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode; 
        if (kCode == 9) {
            $("#TextBox2").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't waste your time manually doing this work!  Utilize the `tabindex` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you're using the `keypress` event, which should only be fired when a character is added to the input, not when any key (like TAB) is pressed.

To handle other key presses you will need to use `keydown`. However, testing that in your fiddle seems to still not work. To make it work (in Chrome at least), I had to prevent the default action:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TextBox1").keydown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode; 
        console.log(kCode);
         if (kCode == 9) {
            $("#TextBox2").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/BCqsb/2/). However, if I've understood your question correctly, all you're trying to do is change the focused element when the tab key is pressed... if that's right, why not just use the `tabindex` attribute instead?

Answer (score 3):

The `keypress` event does not fire for <kbd>tab</kbd> (keycode 9).  You'll need to use `keyup` or `keydown`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is ASP.NET, you need to reference the controls by the `ClientID`:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").keypress(function (e) { 
        var kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;  
         if (kCode == 9) { 
            $("#<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").focus(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Good point, but probably a red herring.  It works in FireFox so the selector is correct.  This is due to the differences in how browsers handle different key events.  Firefox raises a keypress event for tab, while other browsers do not.

Comment: Yea, I thought that was a bit strange too. It's a bit strange that there are no `INamingContainers` though too (assuming `ClientIDMode` is not set to static).